# For Android 13 runtime permission changes, how many times can I show the system dialog per installation?

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications

For the new runtime permissions Android has come up for version 13, how many times can I invoke the system dialog box? Even with the rationale screen, can I invoke it infinitely or is there a limit for every user?
Bumped up the SDK to 33 and OS running on 13.

Answer (score 5):

In my understanding, this is the general rule that applies to permission dialog visibility for android 11 and above:

> Starting in Android 11, if the user taps Deny for a specific
> permission more than once during your app's lifetime of installation
> on a device, the user doesn't see the system permissions dialog if
> your app requests that permission again. The user's action implies
> "don't ask again." On previous versions, users would see the system
> permissions dialog each time your app requested a permission, unless
> the user had previously selected a "don't ask again" checkbox or
> option. This behavior change in Android 11 discourages repeated
> requests for permissions that users have chosen to deny.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/permissions#dialog-visibility

Basically, pressing two times "deny", makes the permission "permanently denied", and, from then on, the system dialog doesn't show, rather, you will immediately get the result isGranted = false, for that permission.

---

On a side note, I could also find something like this in the documentation:

> In certain situations, the permission might be denied automatically,
> without the user taking any action. (A permission might be granted
> automatically as well.) It's important to not assume anything about
> automatic behavior. Each time your app needs to access functionality
> that requires a permission, check that your app is still granted that
> permission.

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#handle-denial

I am not really sure what are those automatic behaviors that the documentation refers to. The only thing that comes to my mind is that maybe it's referring to the fact that the user can also grant/deny a permission from application details setting, and this is something that you as a developer won't have that much control over. Or, maybe it refers to thing from the top (your question), that denying a permission more than once - makes it automatically "permanently" denied, and similar.

Answer (score 0):

There is no strict limit, but there is an option to check "Don't ask again" when denying permissions. In that case you will not be able to display permission requests again(for the given permission).

> When the system asks the user to grant a permission, **the user has
> the option of telling the system not to ask for that permission again.
> In that case, any time an app uses requestPermissions() to ask for
> that permission again, the system immediately denies the request.**
> The system calls your onRequestPermissionsResult() callback method and
> passes PERMISSION_DENIED, the same way it would if the user had
> explicitly rejected your request again. This means that when you call
> requestPermissions(), you cannot assume that any direct interaction
> with the user has taken place.

Comment: I dont see in Android 13 the option "Dont ask again"...